# ROS-Industrial(Hydro) Training Exercises 3.6

Tags: ros, ros-industrial, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all

I'm now following ROS-Industrial(Hydro) Training Exercises 3.6

I can finish the Exercise 3.6.1 which create a random motion for my robot.

Now when I try to do the next step, set a specific goal position, I had a problem.

I follow the instructions said:
"
copy the original example file to lesson_move_group_2,
modify the relevant sections,
and add the new lines to your CMakeLists.txt."
after the `catkin_make` and `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` everything works just fine. Like this:

However, when I do `rosrun lesson_move_group lesson_move_group_2`

there is an error :

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named lesson_move_group_2 below /home/viki/catkin_ws/src/lesson_move_group
```

which seems the lesson_move_group_2 doesn't build correctly.

Then I go to cakin_ws/devel/lib/lesson_move_group/  I found a file named "lesson_move_group_1" like a binary file. If I copy this lesson_move_group_1 file and rename it to lesson_move_group_2, then it can do `rosrun lesson_move_group lesson_move_group_2`. The robot will execute a random movement, just like runing the lesson_move_group_1.

So, I thought,  `catkin_make` and `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` didn't build the binary file for lesson_move_group_2.

Is my suggestion correct? and if it is then what should I do?

this is the link of the tutorial:  http://aeswiki.datasys.swri.edu/rositraining/Exercises/3.6

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196857/ros-industrial(hydro)-training-exercises-3.6/) by [sara](https://answers.ros.org/users/20392/sara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2014-11-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on 2014-11-06**:
Please post the "new lines" you added to CMakeLists.txt.  It sounds like your file isn't building.  This could be the result of a bad CMakeLists or a compile problem.

**Comment by [sara](https://answers.ros.org/users/20392/sara/) on 2014-11-06**:
I add these into the CMakeLists.txt

add_executable(lesson_move_group_2 src/lesson_move_group_2.cpp)
target_link_libraries(lesson_move_group_2 ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Included in the ROS-I training is the solution to every exercise.  You can search through the directories, or you can go directly there using **training_ref *3.6*** on the command line.  If you use the command line function, this will setup the workspace and build everything.  This should demonstrate the final solution to the exercise.

If you want to see what may be causing your specific issue, I recommend diffing the ref and work directories.

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2014-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1